# Белый список для 80 порта

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, iptables

Как можно сделать белый список для n (около 300 и в планах вырастит до 700) числа ip адресов к 80 порту?

Информация о сервере:
Ubuntu v16.04.1 (Linux v4.4.0-31) и Nginx v1.11.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нужно добавить в конфигурацию виртуального хоста примерно следующие строки, если вы хотите это сделать через NGINX

```
location / { 
  allow 100.23.45.14;  ## IP которому нужно разрешить доступ
  allow 100.23.45.15;  ## IP которому нужно разрешить доступ
  deny all;
}
```

Если хотите сделать это через Iptables, то вам требуется прописать следующие строки:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s <allowed_ip> -p tcp --dport 80  -i eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 80
```

Первую строку нужно повторять столько раз, сколько нужно добавить IP в список разрешенных.

Рассмотрим параметры iptables:

- I: Вставка правила в начало
- A: Вставить правило в конец
- s: IP-адрес источника
- j: Выполнить действие, если пакету соответствует текущее правило (ACCEPT принять пакет, DROP блокирование пакета)
- p: Протокол
- dport: Порт, через который ожидается пакет
- i: Интерфейс

Comment: ТС конечно кол-во ip не сказал, но если их вдруг много, то iptables начнет тормозить ядро (при >1000 правил). Настоятельно рекомендуется ветвить правила на цепочки или использовать ipset

Comment: А что менее ресурса затратное в плане блокировки NGINX, iptables или ipset, если речь идет о списке из +300 тысячи адресов?

Comment: @Skar404, Из предложенных решений, конечно ipset, благодаря алгоритмам хэширования, время ответа почти не зависит от размера таблицы, в отличии от iptables который имеет линейный рост времени ответа (сравнение всех правил).

Comment: Зависит от того что блокируем - весь трафик или все-таки именно конкретные сайты. Iptables точно не рекомендую, т.к. он работает в режиме ядра и процессор на таком количестве правил хорошо подъест

Answer (score 3):

Допишу как отдельный ответ, я его уже дал в комментариях к предыдущему ответу, просто форматирование теряется в комментариях.

Во-первых, для nginx нужно выделить все `allow` в отдельный файл -- чтобы не захламлять конфиг-файл и улучшить читаемость.

```
location / {
    include whitelist.txt;
}
```

Файл `whitelist.txt`:

```
  allow 100.23.45.14;
  allow 100.23.45.15;
  deny all;
```

Во-вторых, проскальзывало в комментариях про большое количество хостов: не забывайте, что `nginx` (в отличие от `apache`, который до сих пор не умеет, позор!) понимает подсети:

```
# Rostelecom provider, Belgorod
allow 213.24.126.0/24;

deny all;
```

Answer (score 3):

Для белого списка использовал ipset + iptables

Создаем 2 новые списков:

```
ipset -N whitelist iphash # Для адресов 
ipset -N whitelist_net nethash  # Для сетей
```

Добавить новые адреса в whitelist:

```
ipset -A whitelist 100.23.45.14
ipset -A whitelist_net 100.23.45.0/24
```

Создается правило для использования списков:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set whitelist src -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set whitelist_net src -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

и закрываем 80:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP -p tcp --dport 80
```

---

Дополнительная информация:

https://habrahabr.ru/post/108691/